# Android - How to get the mobile nunber when not stored in the SIM card

Tags: android

I want to get the mobile number related with a SIM card. But I know that some celular operators doesn't store the number into the SIM card.

So use the code below will not return anything,

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getApplicationContext()
                                            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String phoneNumber =  tm.getLine1Number();
```

Anyone knows any other way to get the mobile number?

Maybe some API that retrieves the number using the IMSI of the SIM Card, or maybe the mobile number is stored somewhere on the memory of the device.

One desperate way could be make some kind of request to the operator or carrier to ask for the mobile number for that IMSI, I don't know :)

any help will be appreciated :)

thanks

Comment: "So use the code below will not return anything" -- not only that, it might return the wrong value. My SIM, for example, returns a phone number that the SIM had for about 10 minutes before another mobile number was ported to my account.

Comment: @CommonsWare, What do you mean by that? Do you mean that your phone number stored within a SIM card can change?

Comment: "Do you mean that your phone number stored within a SIM card can change?" -- well, I certainly can't rule that out. In my case, I ported an existing number over to my account. The SIM card knows nothing about that -- it is all handled at the carrier.

Answer (score 1):

In that event I would just have the user input their phone number and cache it.

*EDIT AFTER COMMENT*
I am not 100% sure, but is there a way to grab the phone number stored in the "About Phone" settings menu? Though that probably grabs the phone number from the SIM as well, and if the OS itself can't figure it out, you might have to just settle for not grabbing the phone number on all devices. My phone number is not stored on my SIM, and my About Phone menu can not see my phone number.

Comment: I see, but I forgot to say that that's not an option, the application have to 'collect' some information, like IMEI, OS, SIM card serial numnber, video resolution, audio info, etc... of the device and send it to a server, without 'bother' the user :)

Comment: Can I get the name of that app, so that I may take a note never to install it? How about PrivacySpy, or, even better WeGiveAwayYourPersonalDataToAnyoneWhoPaysForit? :)

Answer (score 1):

I **hope** that no such API exists, or otherwise I foresee being called all day long by some call centers trying to sell useless stuff.